# Should I use VAR or VECM if my variables are I(1) but I want to assume that one of my variables are exogenous?

Tags: vector-autoregression, vector-error-correction-model

I am studying macroeconomic variables, one of which is the money supply.

Initially, I planned to use a SVAR model and assume that money supply is exogenous. However, I discovered that two of the variables I am studying are I(1). I know that I could use a VECM if my variables are cointegrated, but then I am assuming that there are no exogenous variables, even though I want to assume that money supply is exogenous.

I also know that I should not first difference the variables.

My question is should I use a SVAR model even if the variables are I(1) or should I use VECM and ignore the exogeneity of money?

Comment: Why cannot you use VECM with an exogenous variable? If you can have one in (S)VAR, you should be able to in VECM as well, as VECM is just an alternative representation of the same process.

Comment: Thank you Richard! Now I am thinking that I should use ARDL instead because I have a mix of I(0) and I(1) variables. I also use a bounds test and found that my variables are cointegrated so I am going to run a VECM, as well.